# How can I convert the list string to a float

Tags: python, csv, floating-point

I'm using the Python turtle to map out hurricane Irma's path. After reading the file and obtaining the useful data (latitude, longitude, and wind speed), I was getting errors about how the mapping section of the code cannot accept strings. But when I tried to convert the list values to float, it gives me the ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'. I tried using .split, but then I get the error: not enough values to unpack.

```
#open the file and extract the data
    with open("irma.csv", 'rt') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            latitude = row["Lat"]
            longitude = row["Lon"]
            windspeed = row["Wind"]

#convert to float
    latitude = [float(i) for i in latitude]
    longitude = [float(i) for i in longitude]

#mapping the data to the Python turtle function
    for lat, lon in latitude, longitude:
        t.setpos(lat, lon)
        for index in windspeed:
            if index < 74:
                t.pencolor("White")
                t.width(2)
            elif 74 <= index <= 95:
                t.pencolor("Blue")
                t.width(4)
            elif 96 <= index <= 110:
                t.pencolor("Green")
                t.width(6)
            elif 111 <= index <= 129:
                t.pencolor("Yellow")
                t.width(8)
            elif 130 <= index <= 156:
                t.pencolor("Orange")
                t.width(10)
            elif windspeed >= 157:
                t.pencolor("Red")
                t.width(12)
```

Comment: What is your problem? Where is the call to `split`?

Comment: Please consider a more useful title for your question. I opened it expecting to vote to close within a few seconds

Comment: `latitude` and on are strings. So if you iterate over them with `for` you iterate over each single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
latitude = [float(i) for i in latitude]
```

There is a problem with this line. `latitude` starts off as a string, for example `"100.5"`. When you do `[float(i) for i in latitude]`, Python iterates over each character in that string and attempts to convert it into a float, effectively doing:

```
latitude = [float("1"), float("0"), float("0"), float("."), float("5")]
```

But `float(".")` fails, because you can't convert a decimal point to a float.

I'm guessing that you actually intended for `latitude` to start off as a *list* of strings, which would become a list of floats after executing this line. If that's the case, then you need to amend your csv-reading code. Currently it assigns string values to `latitude`, `longitude`, and `windspeed`, with each iteration completely overwriting any values that were read in a previous iteration. If you want to accumulate all the values without overwriting, then you need to create the variables as lists and append to them.

```
latitude = []
longitude = []
windspeed = []
#open the file and extract the data
with open("irma.csv", 'rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        latitude.append(row["Lat"])
        longitude.append(row["Lon"])
        windspeed.append(row["Wind"])
```

This should be sufficient by itself, but you can also delete the float-conversion list comprehensions and simply do the conversion directly in this loop. (And while we're at it, let's pluralize the variable names, which is conventional when dealing with list data)

```
latitudes = []
longitudes = []
windspeeds = []
#open the file and extract the data
with open("irma.csv", 'rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        latitudes.append(float(row["Lat"]))
        longitudes.append(float(row["Lon"]))
        windspeeds.append(float(row["Wind"]))
```

Comment: That makes sense that the "." would only be recognized if the latitude was a string and not integers to begin with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
latitude = [float(i) for i in latitude]
```

is iterating over EVERY character in your latitude, including the '.' which cannot be converted to float.  Same problem for longitude.

You don't need list comprehension here.  Simply:

```
latitude = float(latitude)
```

should be what you're looking for unless the latitude and longitude objects contain other characters.

That doesn't appear to be your only issue, though.  Your `for row in reader` loop overwrites latitude and longitude with every pass.

With that in mind, consider using something more like this:

```
with open("irma.csv", 'rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        lat = float(row["Lat"])
        lon = float(row["Lon"])
        windspeed = row["Wind"]
        t.setpos(lat, lon)
        for index in windspeed:
            if index < 74:
                t.pencolor("White")
                t.width(2)
            elif 74 <= index <= 95:
                t.pencolor("Blue")
                t.width(4)
            elif 96 <= index <= 110:
                t.pencolor("Green")
                t.width(6)
            elif 111 <= index <= 129:
                t.pencolor("Yellow")
                t.width(8)
            elif 130 <= index <= 156:
                t.pencolor("Orange")
                t.width(10)
            elif windspeed >= 157:
                t.pencolor("Red")
                t.width(12)
```